# Datatype of image data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, types

I want to store my image data into my MySQL database or table. What appropriate data type in MySQL should I use to store the image data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use one of this field types:

```
BLOB        L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16
MEDIUMBLOB  L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24
LONGBLOB    L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32
```